# Internal JSP requests for Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I have configured an embedded Jetty server and registered JspServlet myself. I am trying to integrate Spring Security, Spring MVC and realised that internal JSP requests are also filtered by Spring Security. Is this expected or my fault?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault. I had configured Spring Security Filter for DispatcherType.Forward.

Before:

```
handler.addFilter(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey(), EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

After:

```
handler.addFilter(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey(), EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC));
```